# Problem with variable scoping in javascript

Tags: javascript, scoping

I was trying to understand the variable scoping in JavaScript. But I didn't understood why below code behaving different from the expected behavior.

```js
'use strict';
function C() {
  console.log(a);
}

function B() {
  let a = 'printing A from B()';
  C();
}

function A() {
  let a = 'printing A from A()';
  B();
}

const a = 'printing A from global context';
A(); // output getting: 'printing A from global context': CORRECT
B(); // output getting: 'printing A from global context' but expected : 'printing A from B()'
C(); // output getting: 'printing A from global context' but expected : 'printing A from A()'
```

Comment: you declare a new variable `a` scoped to each function in `A()` and `B()` but never use any of them. `C()` always prints the global `const a` (which couldn't be reassigned anyway because its a `const`).

Comment: JS uses lexical scoping, not dynamic scoping.

Answer (score 0):

The output is correct.
Functions A and B both have a different scoped a variable, but C has no access to their scope - only to the global scope - which defines const a